# How to use directionLightHelper in react/three-fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to use the `directionalLightHelper` in my NextJS project but am unable to. So far I have tried two methods.

#### Method 1 -

```
const dirLight = useRef<DirectionalLight>(null);

return (
  <Canvas>
    <directionalLight color={"#005F00"} intensity={1} ref={dirLight} />
    <directionalLightHelper light={dirLight} />
  <Canvas>
)
```

In this case I am getting the error `TypeError: light is undefined`

---

#### Method 2 -

I created a `Light` component with the `useHelper` hook and passed that inside the canvas.

```
const Light = () => {
  const dirLight = useRef<DirectionalLight>(null);
  useHelper(dirLight, DirectionalLightHelper, "red");

  return (
    <>
      <directionalLight color={"#005F00"} intensity={1} ref={dirLight} />
    </>
  );
};
```

In this case I am getting a black colored line at the origin. I am confused if the light helper is supposed to look like this or not?

Comment: In the first case the light is undefined because you are not waiting for the reference to be created and trying to render the helper before. Create a conditional rendering statement that will render directional light when the ref is not undefined and it should be ok

Answer (score 1):

I checked the properties the `useHelper` hook takes in and found out that the color comes after the size argument. So doing a few changes to the code made a square appear on the canvas, much similar to what the `DirectionLightHelper` function gives in vanilla three.js.

```
useHelper(dirLight, DirectionalLightHelper, 1, "red");
```

Upon changing the position of the directional light, the helper responds accordingly.